# Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Unable to load theme by specified key: 'pure'

Tags: themes, magento2

i just to install the magento 2.1.i migrate my database thank to the tool provide by magento.it works great!!

but the problem, when i running the frontend i get this error:
`Unable to load theme by specified key: 'pure'`

and when i want to change the theme in administration, i get this error : `Something went wrong while saving this configuration: Unable to load theme by specified key: 'pure'`

i follow many tips such as to empty the table 'change_design', use this command :

di:compile
setup:upgrade
setup:static-content:deploy
indexer:reindex
cache:flush
...

but the problem persist.

do you a know a solution to resolve this problem?
thanks.

ps: 'Pure' is the theme I was using on the website 1.9

Answer (score 7):

i found the solution.in the table 'core_config_data', it is needed to delete this record : 'design/theme/theme_id'.

```
delete from core_config_data where path = 'design/theme/theme_id';
```

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively you can just update that row in the database and change its value with the correct one. Don't forget to clear the cache afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your theme manually in the *theme* table. Just check the *theme* table and use the same logic for the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove following file (if exists).
../app/etc/config.local.php

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue, in that case we need to update table ***design_config_grid_flat*** and column value ***theme_theme_id***

[image]